# Cannot make seleniumbase load with an existed chromium profile

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webautomation, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumbase

Using the code below:

```
    try:
        with SB(headed=True,uc=True,user_data_dir='path/to/Profile 1',browser='chrome') as sb:
           sb.open('hocalhost:1111')
           sb.sleep(2)
    except:
        print('Some error occur!!')
```

Expecting to see seleniumbase do the test on the profile i just speciffed. But it just create a new profile under the directory i passed. Info from `chrome://version`

> **Profile Path**   path/to/Profile 1/Default

and do the test there.
I've tried to use `chromium_arg='--profile-directory='Profile 1'` and also not working.

What can i do to solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I'm seeing. Looks like you misspelled `localhost` in your `open()` line. When using `user_data_dir` with `uc=True`, there may be an issue if your `user_data_dir` contains spaces in the file path (this is especially true if running with PyInstaller). If that didn't help, use either `uc` or `user_data_dir`, but not both together, as `undetected-chromedriver` has multiple open issues with setting the `user_data_dir`, as seen here: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aultrafunkamsterdam%2Fundetected-chromedriver+user_data_dir&type=issues, which includes the issue with the profile directory getting overwritten when setting a custom one: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1232